# Define parameter before calling to the depends task in Ant

Tags: ant

I want to define parameter before calling to the target of the depends task for example:

```
<target name="init">
...
If (mode=true)
  Then...
       Else...
      ...
       </target>
<target name="Create File" depends="init">
...
       ...
       </target>
```

I want to define parameter called mode and give it for example `true` value and I want to do it once I started the "Create File" before calling the depends="init" task because I want the Init task to use this parameter

Can I do this in Ant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this if you are using `depends`, but you can execute `init` target through [antcall task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html).

Here is an example from the above link

```
<target name="Create File">
  <antcall target="init">
    <param name="param1" value="value"/>
  </antcall>
</target>

<target name="init">
  <echo message="param1=${param1}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer another small question : 
can i add another traget:mytarget
is it called before init?
is Ant call the traget by order?
<target name="Create File" depends="mytarget,init">